# Elixir - How to add packages from the command line?

Tags: elixir

I know in Elixir you can add hex packages by going to mix.exs and manually typing them out. I want to know if there is a command similar to Node js's  `npm install name-of-package -s` command. In other words, is there a way to add individual packages by only using the command line.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? Please mention a reason or suggest improvements and not just downvote questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no functionality to add a package from the command line. However, you're not the first to have this idea. See [this discussion](https://elixirforum.com/t/mix-deps-add-functionality/4856) on ElixirForum.